# Simple C struct won't compile

Tags: c, gcc, struct, avr

I'm trying to implement a simple ring buffer using a struct. I have never used structs before and just started to try to understand them. The compiler exits with this error:

```
expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token
```

The error refers to the last two lines.

```
#define MAX_PROCESSES 16

struct ring_buffer{
    uint8_t data[MAX_PROCESSES];
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t count;
    uint8_t write_pos;
    uint8_t read_pos;
};

struct ring_buffer ring_buffer_processes;
ring_buffer_processes.size = MAX_PROCESSES;
ring_buffer_processes->size = MAX_PROCESSES;
```

I've used the to operators just for test purposes to see, if any of it works. This should of course only be one line.

I also tried using "typedef", but that doesn't help either. What is wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Remove the last line , you reach a struct member via the '.' operator

Comment: @Peder It compiles fine: https://godbolt.org/g/j3NO3P

Comment: if this is your whole code , you have to wrap the last two line in a main()

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz - Removing the last line doesn't help. I did now, since two of you pointed out, that it's wrong, but it still won't work.

Comment: @Gar That's it. Thank you. I never would have guessed that.

Comment: You should do some reading about C then

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two mistakes:

1. It is missing the entry point of execution i.e. main()
2. It is trying to access a member using '->' which is used when accessing a member via pointer.

So correcting these points gives us:

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_PROCESSES 16

struct ring_buffer{
    uint8_t data[MAX_PROCESSES];
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t count;
    uint8_t write_pos;
    uint8_t read_pos;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct ring_buffer ring_buffer_processes;
    struct ring_buffer * p_ring_buffer_processes;

    p_ring_buffer_processes = &ring_buffer_processes;
    ring_buffer_processes.size = MAX_PROCESSES;
    p_ring_buffer_processes->size = MAX_PROCESSES;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To access any member of a structure, we use the member access operator (.) but

To access the members of a structure using a pointer to that structure, you must use the `→` operator.

Change the code ..

```
#define MAX_PROCESSES 16

struct ring_buffer{
    uint8_t data[MAX_PROCESSES];
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t count;
    uint8_t write_pos;
    uint8_t read_pos;
};

struct ring_buffer ring_buffer_processes;

void main(){
    ring_buffer_processes.size = MAX_PROCESSES;
    //ring_buffer_processes->size = MAX_PROCESSES; Not required you can access struct variable with . operator.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C Language,A non-pointer object Has been Accessed by using  **.** Operator and A pointer Object has been Accessed by using **->** Operator.

```
     #define MAX_PROCESSES 16

    struct ring_buffer{
        uint8_t data[MAX_PROCESSES];
        uint8_t size;
        uint8_t count;
        uint8_t write_pos;
        uint8_t read_pos;
    };

    struct ring_buffer ring_buffer_processes;
ring_buffer_processes. size = MAX_PROCESSES;

    struct ring_buffer *ptr_ring_buffer_processes;
*ptr_ring_buffer_processes-> size =& MAX_PROCESSES;
```